# Cache results of a time-intensive operation

Tags: python, database, hash, shelve

I have a program ([PatchDock](http://bioinfo3d.cs.tau.ac.il/PatchDock/)), which takes its input from a parameters file, and produces an output file. Running this program is time-intensive, and I'd like to cache results of past runs so that I need not run the same parameters twice.

I'm able to parse the input and output files into appropriate data structures. The input file, for example, is parsed into a dictionary-like object. The input keys are all strings, and the values are primitive data types (ints, strings, and floats).

#### My approach

My first idea was to use the md5 hash of the input file as the keys in a [`shelve`](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html) database. However, this fails to capture cached files with the exact same inputs, but some slight differences in the input files (comments, spacing, order of parameters, et cetera).

Hashing the parsed parameters seems like the best approach to me. But the only way I can think of getting a unique hash from a dictionary is to hash a sorted string representation.

#### Question

Hashing a string representation of a parameters dictionary seems like a roundabout way of achieving my end goal- keying unique input values to a specified output. Is there a more straightforward way to achieve this caching system?

Ideally, I'm looking to achieve this in Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashing a sorted representation of the parsed input is actually the most straightforward way of doing this, and the one that makes sense. Your instincts were correct.

Basically, you're normalizing the input (by parsing it and sorting it), and then using that to construct a hash key.

Answer (score 2):

Hashing seems a very viable way, but doing this yourself seems a bit overkill. Why not use the tuple of inputs as key for your dictionary? You wouldn't have to worry about hashing and possible collisions yourself. All you have to do is fix a order for the keyword arguments (and depending on your requirements add a flag-object for keywords that are not set).

You also might find the [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) useful, if you are using Python 3.2+.
This is a decorator that will enable caching for the last n calls of the decorated function.
If you are using a older version there are [backports of this functionality out there](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078-py26-and-py30-backport-of-python-33s-lru-cache/).

Also there seem to be a project with similar goals called [FileDict](http://erezsh.wordpress.com/2009/05/24/filedict-a-persistent-dictionary-in-python/) which might be worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that out (I'm stuck on 2.7 for the time being). The reason I'm hashing myself is that a `shelf` database only takes strings as keys (and I need a persistent dictionary). Otherwise I would certainly stick to the tuples. I'm going to use a secure hash algorithm, so collisions really aren't a big worry.

Comment: I'm a big proponent of using built-in data structures, and an LRU cache is _almost_ perfect for my needs (I would just set `maxsize` to `None`). However, I'm looking for a persistent dictionary. If I modify the internal storage mechanism to be a `shelve` dictionary, we're right back to the same problem: `shelve` dicts only allow strings as keys, so I'd have to hash inputs to get a unique key. At this point, my data structure hardly resembles a LRU cache, and writing a simple databes myself would actually prove cleaner. Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I see the problem, but can't think of a simpler solution right now. But I did find a very similar project that you might find useful. See the edited answer.

Comment: Many thanks for your research and advice on this one. I stumbled across FileDict as well, and I'll think I'll stick with my current solution, as it uses mature built-in modules.